# Using result value of the future

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future

Let's say I have this simple psedo example

```
val a: Future[String] = getValA //Assume asynchronous REST call
val b: String = getValB
val c: String = getValC

val d = a + b + c

//rest of the code
```

Now this obviously is not gonna work. I've looked into using future `onComplete` callback but that is not convenient for my case either, because it's return type is `Unit` and it is invoked as soon as future is available. Is there any other way to get the result value from the future except the callback?

For example if the future of `val a` is not complete by the time of `val d` expression, block it until complete, then use the value when it becomes available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`, like this, to combine the values into a future:

```
val d: Future[String] = a.map { _ + b + c }
```

Or, if you absolutely must get the value right there, you can do a blocking call:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val d: String = Await.result(a, 0 nanos) + b + c
```

Helpful reading: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Using the second approach I'm getting `TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [0 nanoseconds]` error all the time.

Comment: Give it more time to finish, either a positive finite duration or Duration.Inf for unbounded waiting. 0 nanos means no waiting.